# How to retrieve images from folder using python Open CV in google colab to test model's performance and print all the images into csv file

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, export-to-csv

I trained a CNN model in Google Colab using train folder. After building model, I want to check model on test folder(all images) and print it to csv file.
I have used below code to check model on random image in test folder. But now I want to check on entire images in the test folder and print to csv file.

Testing using random image with below code

```
 random_filename = random.choice([
    x for x in os.listdir(test_directory)
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(test_directory, x))])
 random_filename=test_directory + random_filename
 print(random_filename)
 img_array = cv2.imread(random_filename,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
 RGB_img = cv2.cvtColor(img_array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
 new_img = cv2.resize(RGB_img,(img_size,img_size))
 print('Prediction : {}'.format(model.predict_classes(new_img.reshape(-1,img_size,img_size,3))))
 plt.imshow(new_img)
 plt.show()
```